# Simple cookie to keep background settings

Tags: javascript, cookies, colors, background, onclick

OK, so I've put a code with optional page backgrounds users can choose from, but I need to write a cookie so that the user's preferred background colour stays as selected even after page refresh. I've looked at a dozen tutorials but I'm hopeless implementing any of them to this case.

Here's the code:

```
    <script style='text/javascript' type='text/javascript'>
var backColour = new Array();

backColour[0] = &#39;#FFFFFF&#39;;
backColour[1] = &#39;#000000&#39;;

function changeBG(whichColour){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backColour[whichColour];
}
 </script>
```

And the clickable links that set the background:

```
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:changeBG(0);'>//WHITE</a>
   <a href='#' onclick='javascript:changeBG(1);'>//BLACK</a>
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`document.cookie = 'mybg=' + theBGColor + ';';` to write out the cookie.

and

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf('mybg=') != -1) {
    mybg = document.cookie.split('mybg=')[1].split(';')[0];
}
```

to read back the color from the cookie

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, take a look at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie